How to compute this integral $\int_i^f \frac{d\boldsymbol{p}}{dt}\cdot d\boldsymbol{x}$
I am struggling to understand this integral from page 6 of these notes:
$$K_f-K_i=\int_i^f \frac{d\boldsymbol{p}}{dt}\cdot d\boldsymbol{x}=m\int_i^f\boldsymbol{u}\cdot d\boldsymbol{u}=\frac12m(u_f^2-u_i^2)$$
How to get the second and third equalities? The "physics way of doing things" would consider $\frac{d\boldsymbol{p}}{dt}$ as fractions. The calculation would look like
$$\int_i^f \frac{d\boldsymbol{p}}{dt}\cdot d\boldsymbol{x}=m\int_i^f \frac{d\boldsymbol{u}}{dt}\cdot \boldsymbol{u}dt=m\int_i^f d\boldsymbol{u}\cdot\boldsymbol{u}=m\int_i^f \boldsymbol{u}\cdot d\boldsymbol{u}$$
In the third equality, I treated $dt$ as real numbers and cancelled them.
I wonder how to do compute this integral in more mathematical way.

Physicists' abuses of notations are nothing else than shortcuts for more rigorous techniques. In the present case, the first step, namely $\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}t$, corresponds to a mere substitution / change of variable. Indeed, the variable $x$ is itself parametrized by the time $t$, hence $x = f(t)$ $-$ usually written as $x = x(t)$ by another common abuse of notation in physics, where the variable $x$ is conflated with its functional relation with $t$ $-$ and finally $\mathrm{d}x = f'(t)\mathrm{d}t$, where $f'(t) = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$ is nothing else than the Jacobian of the said change of variable. Since $p = m\dot{x} = mf'(t)$, we end up with
$$
\int_{x_i}^{x_f} \frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t} \mathrm{d}x = m\int_{t_i}^{t_f} f''(t)f'(t) \mathrm{d}t
$$
Now, the second step, where the two $\mathrm{d}t$'s cancel each other, leaving $\mathrm{d}u$ alone, is achieved with the help of another change of variable, namely $u = \dot{x} = f'(t)$, whose Jacobian is precisely given by $f''(t)$, hence $\mathrm{d}u = f''(t)\mathrm{d}t$ and finally
$$
\int_{t_i}^{t_f} f'(t)f''(t) \mathrm{d}t = \int_{u_i}^{u_f} u \,\mathrm{d}u.
$$
As a side note, let's highlight that the quantity $f'(t)f''(t)$ corresponds to the total derivative $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{1}{2}f'(t)^2\right)$, so that, alternatively, it can be integrated straightforwardly thanks to the fundamental theorem of calculus, i.e.
$$
m\int_{t_i}^{t_f} f'(t)f''(t) \mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{2}m\int_{t_i}^{t_f} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(f'(t)^2\right) \mathrm{d}t =  \left.\frac{1}{2}mf'(t)^2\right|_{t_i}^{t_f} = K_f-K_i
$$

@YvesDaoust. Being myself a physicist, I agree with you, but OP wanted to avoid such manipulations.

Thank you. I believe $\frac{1}{2}m\int_{t_i}^{t_f} f'(t)^2 \mathrm{d}t$ should be $\frac{1}{2}m\int_{t_i}^{t_f} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(f'(t)^2) \mathrm{d}t$. Also, can you elaborate how did you perform 1D change of variables using Jacobian?

@user366875. I forgot the derivative symbol indeed, it is now corrected. A 1D Jacobian contains a single component (and thus a single derivative), such that the change of variable $x \mapsto y := \phi(x)$ leads to $\mathrm{d}y = \phi'(x)\mathrm{d}x$ or conversely $\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\phi'(\phi^{-1}(y))}$.

This follows from the definition of a differential, which is infinitesimal change in $u$ w.r.t $t$.
$$\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta t}=\frac{du}{dt}\implies du=\bigg(\frac{du}{dt}\bigg) dt$$
So although it looks like cancellation in fractions, it's basically  $$\text{(derivative)}.\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\Delta t=u'(t) dt=du$$
Hence the integrand becomes $m\int u \ du$

@YvesDaoust how so? I totally believe you,  but can I get a broader explanation for your reply? Thanks in advance :)

@YvesDaoust what about the introduction of this page?

@YvesDaoust sorry for the previous arguments, I learnt the difference between rigorous and non rigorous just now :") Can you suggest me a way to correct my answer?
